# jQuery Mobile and PhoneGap : body background during transition

Tags: ios, cordova, jquery-mobile, transition

Since I have upgraded jQuery Mobile to 1.3 and PhoneGap to 2.5, I have a problem for page changing in my iOS application.

When I click to a link, for a few milliseconds, I see a "no page" state. It's not a white screen, but the background of my "body" element.
I have made some researches on the web, but it looks like no tricks work for me. Most of them tell to disable transition of jQM. But it is already the case for me.

I have tracked jQM event to see what happens, and apparently when I use the method changePage(), it hides the current page, and then show the final page. And during these two methods, I can see this "no page" state, with my body background.

So it is not the flickering navigation that occurs during transition (because I disabled transition), it's something else.

Anyone would have a suggestion to fix this annoying problem (I cannot post image with my reputation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has some suggestions on changing the `$.mobile.defaultTransitionHandler` to use the `simultaneousHandler` instead of the default `sequentialHandler`.

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4024

This has improved page transition speed in my application (with $.mobile.defaultPageTransition set to 'none'), but I am still dealing with occasional white flashes.

Comment: It seems to work for me.I hope they will include it in the next version of jQM (or something similar).Thanks.